# What can I do when the LocationCallback in Android does not work and does not give a result?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get my location in a separate class (functions.java) that can be called in from the MainActivity. I am using intent to get the data back to the MainActivity. I had the function `getCurrentGPSLocation()` in my MainActivity first and it worked fine, but I needed to put it into a separate class as I want to use it for a foreground service as well.

The LocationRequest works, but I have found out that the LocationCallback does not work as everything belonging to the LocationCallback is ignored (I checked it by putting the string `ser_Location = "London";` in and outside the brackets of the LocationCallback.) So I do not get any location result.

Where is my mistake in the code?

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Functions extends AppCompatActivity {

    //initialize variable
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private double ser_Latitude;
    private double ser_Longitude;
    private String ser_Accuracy;
    private String ser_Altitude;
    private String currentDateandTime;
    private String ser_Location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Boolean precision = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("precision", true);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(
                Functions.this);
        getCurrentGPSLocation();

         Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.putExtra("latitude", ser_Latitude);
        intent.putExtra("longitude", ser_Longitude);
        intent.putExtra("accuracy", ser_Accuracy);
        intent.putExtra("altitude", ser_Altitude);
        intent.putExtra("location", ser_Location);
        intent.putExtra("currentDateandTime", currentDateandTime);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        Functions.this.finish();
    }

    //Force new GPS Location Request
    private void getCurrentGPSLocation() {
        // get the new location from the fused client
        // update the UI - i.e. set all properties in their associated text view items

        //Initialize new location request
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(3000)
                .setFastestInterval(2000)
                .setNumUpdates(1)
                ;

        //Initialize location call back
        LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override

            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

                //Initialize location1
                Location location1 = locationResult.getLastLocation();

                //Set latitude
                ser_Latitude = location1.getLatitude();
                //Set longitude
                ser_Longitude = location1.getLongitude();
                //Set Accuracy
                double ser_accura1 = location1.getAccuracy();
                ser_Accuracy = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(ser_accura1) + " m";
                //Set Altitude
                double ser_altit1 = location1.getAltitude();
                ser_Altitude = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(ser_altit1) + " m";

                //Get Adress
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(ser_Latitude, ser_Longitude, 1);
                    if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                        String _Location1 = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        //Set Location
                        //ser_Location = String.valueOf(_Location1);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ser_Location = "London";
                //Set Update Time
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy 'um ' HH:mm:ss z");
                currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

            }
        };
        
        //Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest
                , locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }

}
```

Thanks to the comments I can now get the intent to the MainActivity with the following code, having put the intent into the onResult part:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Functions extends AppCompatActivity {

    //initialize variable
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private double ser_Latitude;
    private double ser_Longitude;
    private String ser_Accuracy;
    private String ser_Altitude;
    private String currentDateandTime;
    private String ser_Location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Boolean precision = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("precision", true);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(
                Functions.this);
        getCurrentGPSLocation();

   /*     Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.putExtra("latitude", ser_Latitude);
        intent.putExtra("longitude", ser_Longitude);
        intent.putExtra("accuracy", ser_Accuracy);
        intent.putExtra("altitude", ser_Altitude);
        intent.putExtra("location", ser_Location);
        intent.putExtra("currentDateandTime", currentDateandTime);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        Functions.this.finish();*/
    }

    //Force new GPS Location Request
    private void getCurrentGPSLocation() {
        // get the new location from the fused client
        // update the UI - i.e. set all properties in their associated text view items

        //Initialize new location request
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(3000)
                .setFastestInterval(2000)
                .setNumUpdates(3)
                ;
        Log.d("LocationRequest", "Request done");
        //Initialize location call back
        LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override

            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                Log.d("LocationCallback", "Callback started");
                //Initialize location1
                Location location1 = locationResult.getLastLocation();

                //Set latitude
                ser_Latitude = location1.getLatitude();
                //Set longitude
                ser_Longitude = location1.getLongitude();
                //Set Accuracy
                double ser_accura1 = location1.getAccuracy();
                ser_Accuracy = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(ser_accura1) + " m";
                //Set Altitude
                double ser_altit1 = location1.getAltitude();
                ser_Altitude = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(ser_altit1) + " m";

                //Get Adress
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(ser_Latitude, ser_Longitude, 1);
                    if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                        String _Location1 = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        //Set Location
                        //ser_Location = String.valueOf(_Location1);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ser_Location = "London";
                //Set Update Time
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy 'um ' HH:mm:ss z");
                currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Double.toString(ser_Longitude),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.putExtra("latitude", ser_Latitude);
                intent.putExtra("longitude", ser_Longitude);
                intent.putExtra("accuracy", ser_Accuracy);
                intent.putExtra("altitude", ser_Altitude);
                intent.putExtra("location", ser_Location);
                intent.putExtra("currentDateandTime", currentDateandTime);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                Functions.this.finish();
            }
        };

        //Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest
                , locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

    }

}
```

Now `onLocationResult` happens three times when I set the NumUpdates to 3 to get a higher precision (I can see that in the toast messages with the longitude and in the Log `Callback started`). I want to have the last update result being handed over. This version hands over the result of the first location update. So this is only half of the solution.

And it returns the following warning: `Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` However, this could be a completely different problem, so don't worry too much about it.

Comment: It looks like you're finishing the activity before you've received any location updates?

Comment: I can see that the location is requested with the GPS flag at the top of the screen. If I set the number of location updates higher the flag remains longer. As I said, the locationRequest seems to work but I cannot get the location results in the LocationCallback. Maybe there is another way of getting the location result from the LocationRequest?

Comment: What flag are you referring to? Is `onLocationResult` getting called?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the little icon on the device showing that the GPS is being used. `onLocationResult`is not getting called, I think - how can I check that?

Comment: Print out something from the `Log` in `onLocationResult`? Then if that prints, you know it's just a mistake with what you're doing when it triggers.

Comment: `onLocationResult` is being called, even the location is retrieved - I checked with a Toast displaying `ser_Accuracy` right after getting the accuracy. So the problem seems to be how I can get the content of the variables for location into the intent to send them to the `MainActivity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here we go - I found a solution for the last problem. I added a counter and made the intent be triggered when the counter reaches the number of requested location updates. Now everything works fine.
Thanks for your help!

```
package com.example.currentlocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Functions extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int NUM_UPDATES = 8;
    //initialize variable
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private double ser_Latitude;
    private double ser_Longitude;
    private String ser_Accuracy;
    private String ser_Altitude;
    private String currentDateandTime;
    private String ser_Location;
    int i = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Boolean precision = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("precision", true);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(
                Functions.this);
        getCurrentGPSLocation();
       }

    //Force new GPS Location Request
    private void getCurrentGPSLocation() {
        // get the new location from the fused client
        // update the UI - i.e. set all properties in their associated text view items

        //Initialize new location request
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(2500)
                .setFastestInterval(1500)
                .setNumUpdates(NUM_UPDATES)
                ;
        Log.d("LocationRequest", "Request done");

        //Initialize location call back
        LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override

            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                Log.d("LocationCallback", "Callback started");
                //Initialize location1
                Location location1 = locationResult.getLastLocation();

                //Set latitude
                ser_Latitude = location1.getLatitude();
                //Set longitude
                ser_Longitude = location1.getLongitude();
                //Set Accuracy
                double ser_accura1 = location1.getAccuracy();
                ser_Accuracy = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(ser_accura1) + " m";
                //Set Altitude
                double ser_altit1 = location1.getAltitude();
                ser_Altitude = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(ser_altit1) + " m";

                //Get Adress
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(ser_Latitude, ser_Longitude, 1);
                    if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                        String _Location1 = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        //Set Location
                        ser_Location = String.valueOf(_Location1);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Set Update Time
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy 'um ' HH:mm:ss z");
                currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ser_Accuracy,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (i==NUM_UPDATES) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.putExtra("latitude", ser_Latitude);
                intent.putExtra("longitude", ser_Longitude);
                intent.putExtra("accuracy", ser_Accuracy);
                intent.putExtra("altitude", ser_Altitude);
                intent.putExtra("location", ser_Location);
                intent.putExtra("currentDateandTime", currentDateandTime);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                Functions.this.finish();}
                else {i++;}
            }
        };

        //Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest
                , locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

    }

}
```

Comment: You should edit your post if you're trying to clarify your problem, this isn't an answer to your question.

Comment: I hope now everything is ok - I edited my answer and can now provide the complete answer.